# UnicodeDecodeError caused by the key <bs>

Tags: python

To simplify the problem, run following command will get the same error

```
:py3 print(vim.eval('"\\<bs>"'))
```

And the real situation is

```python
while 1:
    vimcmd("let nr = getchar()")
    vimcmd("let ch = type(nr) ? nr : nr2char(nr)")
    if vimeval('ch == "\\<bs>"') == '1':
        dosomething
    ...
```

Comment: Just a guess but maybe related to `:h Linux-backspace` ...?

Comment: Other folks have historically had problems with backspace. In addition to the help section above there's `:h :fixdel` and this from Vim wiki: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Backspace_and_delete_problems . ... perhaps some clues can be found there.

Comment: @BLayer I have no problem using backspace with vim when editing file. Have you run `:py3 print(vim.eval('"\\<bs>"'))` and what is the result?

Comment: @BLayer Thanks for the information you provide and sorry for my word. I do not fill you bothered but want to know that you think the possible reason is more about linux or terminals but not vim itself? This is first time I came with this error.

Comment: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1053#issuecomment-749006074

Comment: Fixed in 8.2.2178 (as of 22 minutes ago, amazing!) @user938271 please post it as an answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it fixed the issue for some strings but not all apparently.  `"\<bs>"` still raises an error (although a bit different).  And the OP is interested in handling a string containing `"\<bs>"`.